# Why is "mantis about" written the way it is in "Look out! mantis about!"

Tags: word-meaning, ellipsis, headlinese

I was reading with my daughter a young learners knowledge book when I came across the text below. There was a picture of a mantis in a plant *catching* a bug.

> **Look out, mantis about**
>
> Many mantids look like leaves. They keep very still, then shoot out their long front legs to grab a passing
>   insect. A mantis has sharp jaws to slice up its prey and scoop out the
>   soft insides.

My question is about the phrase **"mantis about"**.

1- Is there an ellipsis here? and the phrase is in fact "**mantis [*is*] about [to verb]**"

2- If there was an ellipsis, what would the reason be? I mean is it because ellipses is a title? Or because the word "mantis" ends with "s" and so it is appropriate to drop "is" for vocal reasons? Or just for rhyming effects?

By the way I did a Google search and found [this link](http://www.ukmantisforums.co.uk/showthread.php?6154-Look-out!-Mantis-about!) by the same title. Is it a coincidence to have the same rhyming phrase or is it something people say, a fixed phrase or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***About*** is being used with sense 5 as given at [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about):

> in the vicinity :  near

There is an ellipsis, but it is

> Look out,  [there is a] mantis about.

You could consider this to be a "headline-ese" or "announcement/warning" sort of ellipsis, although it does also improve the meter of the phrase to make it a better rhyming couplet.

The phrase as a whole is a sort of catchy, easy to remember reminder that you should pay attention if you want to spot a mantis, since they are often difficult to see.  (Alternatively, it can also be taken as a warning to be careful so that you don't accidentally squish a mantis; or, if mantises were dangerous, it would be a warning to avoid the mantis that is in the area.)

I've never heard the phrase before, but since it is a short phrase with an easy, obvious rhyme, I wouldn't be surprised if many mantis-loving people came up with it independently.

Comment: "Look out" is a complete sentence, but "mantis about" is just a clause. Grammatically, it cannot stand alone or that's what I think.
Regardless of being rhymey here, and grammar wise, can I say: Look out, the **bad boy about**? Can I use this form: (proper name + about) with no verb?

Comment: okay, there IS an ellipsis, but not the one you mentioned.  I will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I read the sentence as

Look out, (a) mantis (is) about.

Possibly because I unconsciously eschew "there is" sentences.

Comment: I thought of many and this was one of them